# Issue generating PHP page from another PHP page

Tags: php, html

I have this form which is generated by a form,

```
    <?php while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['id'])?></td>
        <td><a href = "details.php"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['type_code']); ?></a></td>
        <th><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['connector_type']); ?></td>
        <th><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['construction_type']); ?></td>
        <th><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['start_passband']); ?></td>
        <th><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['stop_passband']); ?></td>
        <th><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['lower_stopband_start']); ?></td>
        <th><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['lower_stopband_stop']); ?></td>
        <th><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['upper_stopband_start']); ?></td>
        <th><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['upper_stopband_stop']); ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
</tbody>
```

As you can see, the second row, type_code links to another page, "details.php" - I want to get that page to be generated from information accrued from the 'type_code'. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: `<a href="details.php?id=<?php echo intval($row['id'])?>">`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol In ``details.php``, don't forget to check that ``$_GET['id']`` is actually a valid integer and a valid id: one could visit ``details.php?id=*`` by typing it in their adress bar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All you have to do is to pass your id in URL :

```
<a href="details.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">link</a>
```

Then in you details.php page you can retreive datas like so

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'";
```

You obviously want to add verifications on top of that to secure your page

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && (int)$_GET['id']) {
   $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'";
   // build your page
} else {
   header('Location: index.html'); // or whatever else
}
```

Comment: To avoid injection, instead of may-be-forgotten-previous-checks, use prepared statements, or use a new secured variable ``$id=(int)$_GET['id'];`` or simply ``$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '" . (int)($_GET['id']) . "'";``

Comment: @Pye You should include said verifications in your answer, rather than giving incredibly insecure code that *will* be used by people no matter how many warnings you give. For that, -1.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I added usual verifications. But people can add more, depending of their needs

Comment: That's not secure enough. `(int)"123'; drop table Students; --"` becomes `123`, which passes your "test".

Comment: Thanks, i ended up using $_GET at the end! /t